# Bouvet Island volcano

Tags: volcanology, volcanic-eruption, islands

In this remote island (the most remote!) there is a volcano that wikipedia report as inactive, but from google maps there seems to be some ash in the sky. Are there some ongoing eruption?
[image]

Comment: it is a mountain surounded by water fog happens when humid air is forced upwards.https://volcano.si.edu/volcano.cfm?vn=386020

Comment: ...and Google imagery is typically at least a year or two old.

Comment: @winwaed This one has a ©2021, but if your point is that it's not real time, then yes! :)

Comment: All I see is a blurry picture. I don't think it is at all clear whether that is ash, fog, imaging artifacts, low resolution, or anything else.